# Java - Card Game, Creating the Cards

Tags: java

I am trying to create a deck of cards in Java.

```
package cardgame;

public class CardGame {

    String[] numberList = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
    String[] suitList = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};    
    Card[] deck = new Card[52];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
                deck.add(Card(numberList[j], suitList[i]));
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

Unfortunately this method of adding cards is not working, does anyone have any suggestions? I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: Array.add
    at cardgame.CardGame.main(CardGame.java:12)
```

I have mainly been coding in python so im not sure that my syntax is correct

My Card constructor is below:

```
package cardgame;

public class Card {

    private String number;
    private String suit;

    public Card(String number, String suit) {
        this.number = number;
        this.suit = suit;
    }
```

Comment: Now review instance creation expressions with the `new` keyword.

Comment: Then review array types.

Comment: Tip: don't use arrays here, use a List (e.g. ArrayList).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java arrays don't have an "add" method. They are not objects. You want to say

`deck[i*13+j] = new Card(numberList[j], suitList[i]);`

Assuming you have defined the card class somewhere with that constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create object by call "new"

```
new Card(numberList[j], suitList[i])
```

Also if you use array, you cant use add. You can, however, use list:

```
String[] numberList = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
String[] suitList = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};    
List<Card> deck = new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++) {
            deck.add(new Card(numberList[j], suitList[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I do have a constructor, added it to the post